# DAX Last Year for Count

Tags: powerbi, dax

I’m trying to calculate last year data incorporated in the following measure.

```
   Previous Month = VAR CurrMonth = MONTH ( TODAY () ) RETURN IF ( CurrMonth = 1, 12, CurrMonth - 1 )
```

I’ve tried using PREVIOUSYEAR if the current month is 1 (Jan) but it’s grabbing all previous years.

Comment: Hi, could you provide sample data? Can you explain from what measure you want to calculate previous year? Do you have a calendar table?

Comment: Hello, I was able to get it  :) right after i posted this.